# Missing single quote when using PDFStamper

Tags: java, pdf, coldfusion

I'm using ColdFusion 11 and Java (`com.lowagie.text.pdf.PdfStamper`) to fill in pdf but when I enter a value with a single apostrophe such as `32'` it only saves in the pdf as `32` instead of `32'`. The value is going into a multi-line text area in the PDF. I've tried with and without rich-text enabled.

I've tried replacing `'` with `&#39&#59;`, `''`, `&apos&#59;`, and `\u0027;` but all of them disappear. I've also tried `xmlFormat` but it shows up as `&apos&#59;`.

Copying and pasting the `’` from MS Word didn't work either as a replacement value.

Here is the code I'm using

```
this.pdfFile = this.pdfService.read( source=infile );
this.pdfReader = createObject("java","com.lowagie.text.pdf.PdfReader").init( tobinary( this.pdffile ) );
this.pdfWriter = createObject( "java", "java.io.FileOutputStream").init( CreateObject( "java", "java.io.File" ).init( this.outfile ));
this.pdfStamper = createObject( "java", "com.lowagie.text.pdf.PdfStamper").init( this.pdfReader, this.PdfWriter );
this.acroForm = this.pdfStamper.getAcroFields();
//this.misc.text = replace( this.misc.text, "'", "&##39;", "all");
//this.misc.text = replace( this.misc.text, "'", "\u0027;", "all");
//this.misc.text = replace( this.misc.text, "'", "’", "all");
//this.misc.text = replace( this.misc.text, "'", "'", "all");
//this.misc.text = PreserveSingleQuotes( this.misc.text );
this.acroForm.setField("text", this.misc.text );
```

Comment: Can you do a manual `convertToString (this.misc.text, PdfObject.TEXT_PDFDOCENCODING)` and check if the quote has disappeared at that point?

Comment: @Jongware I tried the following but it didn't work. this.misc.text = this.PdfEncodings.convertToBytes( this.misc.text, this.PdfObject.TEXT_PDFDOCENCODING );
this.misc.text = this.PdfEncodings.convertToString( this.misc.text, this.PdfObject.TEXT_PDFDOCENCODING);

Comment: convertToString expects a byte[] not a string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem ended up being that the Times font that was selected as the font for the input boxes did not have the apostrophe character. Changing the font to Arial or Verdana fixed the problem.

Comment: A hack that worked for me was to print `'\u2019'` instead of the apostrophe. It’s a right single quote. My eye can’t tell the difference.